# Google chrome's cache breaks my Isotope Javascript grid

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, jquery-isotope

**We have a work portfolio** created with the library Isotope in our website.

**Website:** https://www.beedit.es

**Library Isotope:** https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope

The problem is that with Chrome Desktop Browser or Safari iOS Browser (for example), **when you refresh the website** and it has been cached by the browser in local memory, **the grid disappears.**

If you deactivate the cache in the browser the problem disappears, but it isn't a solution.

I've searched and tried many things, such as adding a random version string to the .js library (?v=[RAMDOM), but it does not work, it must be something else.

With the latest version of firefox it does not happen to me.

**Explanatory video:** https://youtu.be/hhuD_1sCbx8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.load event doesn't fire for images that are loaded from the cache.

You can fix that by using

```
    $('#work-container > article > img').one('load',function(){
                $('.isotope-item').show();
                $('.img-wait').fadeIn('fast');
                $('#work-container').isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
                    layoutMode: 'masonry',
                    resizesContainer: true,
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: 300,
                        isFitWidth: true
                    }
                });
            }).error(function(){
            }).each(function(){
                if(this.complete) {
                    $(this).load();
                }
            });
```